# Running AIR application wont appear in Advanced Task Killer

Tags: android, apache-flex, air

I'm developing a demo (flex/air/mobile/android) application, when I launch it on my phone (HTC Desire), I cannot see the running application among running processes in the "Advanced Task Killer". Could you help me why? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what the Advanced Task Killer is.  What are you looking for?  When running on my dev machine; it is usually ADT that I look for in order to "Force Quit".

Answer (score 0):

You probably won't see your app in the Advanced Task Killer (an Android app on Google Play), unless you package your app with the [captive runtime](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/air3-install-and-deployment-options.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader). You might see a process for the Adobe AIR instead (I don't have an Android device to verify).

On PC's and Android, AIR apps can have the AIR framework included with them. The default is to use the AIR runtime on the installed on the PC/Android phone.

You can package your app w/the captive runtime w/`adt`:

```
adt -package -target apk-captive-runtime ...
```